# PHP Pthread pool management

Tags: php, multithreading, php-pthread

(First problem is below)

Finally made it like i wanted ! What a headache ^^

Not using pool was the answer ;)

So, here is my code, output below !

As you can see on the output, i got my jobs distribute evenly between workers 1 & 2 while worker 0 is running a long job !

```
<?php
class ChildThread extends Threaded {
  public $workerId;
  protected $complete;

  public function __construct($workerId){
    // init some properties
    $this->workerId = $workerId;
    $this->complete = false;
  }
  public function run(){
    // do some work
    echo "    STARTING " . $this->workerId . "\r\n";
    if($this->workerId == 0){
        sleep(10);
      } else {
        sleep(1);
      }
    echo "        ENDING " . $this->workerId . "\r\n";
    $this->complete = true;
  }
  public function isComplete() { 
      return $this->complete; 
  }
}

$WORKER_COUNT = 3;

$workers = array();
for ($i=0; $i<$WORKER_COUNT; $i++) {
  $worker = new Worker();
  $worker->start();
  $workers[] = $worker;
}

$tasks = array();
//Create 9 jobs
for ($i=0; $i < 9; $i++) { 
  $tasks[] = new ChildThread($i);
}

$cptTasks = 0;
//References for running jobs
$taskss = array();

while(count($tasks) > 0){
  foreach ($workers as $key => $worker) {
    if($worker->isShutdown()){
      echo "Shutdowned worker ".$key.", restarting it !"."\r\n";
      $worker->start();
    }
    //If worker is free of charge
    if($worker->isWorking() === false ){
      //Check if task not null
      if(isset($tasks[$cptTasks])){
        echo ("Stacking job ".$cptTasks." on worker ".$key."\r\n");
        $worker->stack($tasks[$cptTasks]);
        $taskss[] = $tasks[$cptTasks];
        //Clear job from jobs list
        unset($tasks[$cptTasks]);
        $cptTasks++;
      }
    }
  }
  usleep(2000);
}

//Clear workers
foreach ($workers as $key => $worker) {
  echo "Shutdown worker : " .$key."\r\n";
  $worker->shutdown();
}

?>
```

Output :
    Stacking job 0 on worker 0
    Stacking job 1 on worker 1
    Stacking job 2 on worker 2
        STARTING 1
        STARTING 0
        STARTING 2
            ENDING 1
            ENDING 2
    Stacking job 3 on worker 1
    Stacking job 4 on worker 2
        STARTING 3
        STARTING 4
            ENDING 3
            ENDING 4
    Stacking job 5 on worker 1
    Stacking job 6 on worker 2
        STARTING 5
        STARTING 6
            ENDING 5
            ENDING 6
    Stacking job 7 on worker 1
    Stacking job 8 on worker 2
        STARTING 7
        STARTING 8
    Shutdown worker : 0
            ENDING 8
            ENDING 7
            ENDING 0
    Shutdown worker : 1
    Shutdown worker : 2

---

I'm working on a pthread system, and i'm trying to implement kind of a pool system.

Currently, i'm creating a pool of 3 workers, then send my jobs with pool->submit().

Then, pool->collect()

And pool->shutdown()

But, i'm disapointed with the result.

Jobs seems to be distributed to all workers evenly

Worker 1 : jobs 1, 4, 7

Worker 2 : jobs 2, 5, 8

Worker 3 : jobs 3, 6, 9

Then, let's say my job 1 is pretty long, and all other are not dat long, my jobs will be finished like so :

2, 5, 3, 6, 8, 9, 1, 4, 7

But, what i'd like to achieve should be more like : 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 8, 7, 9, 1

Like distributing jobs to the nearest not working worker, so my heavy job is running on worker 1, and all others jobs goes to workers 2 and 3

Is that's something doable ?

I'm i missing something here ?

Code exemple :

```
    <?php

class ChildThread extends Threaded {
  public $jobId;
  protected $complete;

  public function __construct($jobId){
    // init some properties
    $this->jobId = $jobId;
    $this->complete = false;
  }
  public function run(){
    echo "STARTING " . $this->jobId . "\r\n";
    //Job ID 1 == heavy waiting
    if($this->jobId == 1){
      sleep(10);
    } else {
      sleep(1);
    }
    echo "ENDING " . $this->jobId . "\r\n";

    $this->complete = true;
  }
  public function isComplete() { 
      return $this->complete; 
  }
}


$pool = new Pool(3);
$tasks = array();

// Add tasks to pool queue
for ($i=1; $i<=9; $i++) {
  $task = new ChildThread($i);
  $pool->submit($task);
  $tasks[] = $task;
}

$pool->collect(function($work){
  return $work->isComplete();
});
$pool->shutdown();

?>
```

Result :
    STARTING 1
    STARTING 2
    STARTING 3
    ENDING 2
    STARTING 5
    ENDING 3
    STARTING 6
    ENDING 5
    STARTING 8
    ENDING 6
    STARTING 9
    ENDING 8
    ENDING 9
    ENDING 1
    STARTING 4
    ENDING 4
    STARTING 7
    ENDING 7